# How to arrange items in css grid with auto heights

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to make a fairy simple looking layout with css grid.

[image]

As, shown in above image, i want to place 3 items in a grid in the exact same order as shown in the image, I don't want to set specific height to any of the item, since each of the item have different height depending upon the content in it. I want to give 70% of grid horizontal space to `item1` and 30% to `item2` & `item3`, `item3` should be placed beneath `item2`. Again, heights of items should be `auto`. I am trying to achieve this for many hours but failed to do so.

Markup of the problem:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">some content in it...</div>
  <div class="item2">some Content in it...</div>
  <div class="item3">some Content in it...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Comment: Can you share with us your current attempt?

Comment: And how should they behave? Are they responsive? Will there be more items below item1 or do you want always 2 columns that are separate?

Comment: @F.Müller, I didn't provide code because i think this is fairy simple example and so does not require any lengthy code to show but i try to arrange each item with by apply grid-column on each item but failed to do so. Also, I am not very good with grid right now.

Comment: I want exactly the same layout, 3 items in same order with different heights and yes they should be responsive

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I have provided an answer. Please let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution as requested:

You could use `grid-template-areas` to span the first item across multiple rows. And use a spacer at the end of the right column to make the items just as big as needed.

We can use calc to account for the `grip-gap`.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: calc(70% - 10px) calc(30% - 10px);
  grid-template-areas: "item-1 item-2" "item-1 item-3" "item-1 spacer";
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  align-items: start;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-areas: "item-2" "item-1" "item-3";
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  }
}

.item-1 {
  grid-area: item-1;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-area: item-2;
}

.item-3 {
  grid-area: item-3;
}

.purple {
  background-color: #5B00FF;
}

.red {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.pink {
  background-color: #FF00FD
}

.h-500 {
  height: 500px;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100px;
}

.h-200 {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item-1 purple h-500">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item item-2 red h-100">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item item-3 pink h-200">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

## Alternative solution with different columns:

You could use `grid-gap` along with `grid-template-columns`. You have to take the `grid-gap` into account for the width of template-column That's why there is this calc.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: calc(70% - 10px) calc(30% - 10px);
  border: 1px dashed #000;
}

.col--right {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.purple {
  background-color: #5B00FF;
}

.red {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.pink {
  background-color: #FF00FD
}

.h-500 {
  height: 500px;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100px;
}

.h-200 {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col col--left">
    <div class="item purple h-500">Item 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col--right">
    <div class="item red h-100">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item pink h-200">Item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: appreciate your effort, but as I said in the question, I want 3 items in grid container as shown in the markup provided in the question. You create 2 grid items and then creates 2 columns in grip which is easy to create like this. But I want to arrange 3 items in 2 columns in similar order as shown in the image.

Comment: Reason why I want 3 separate items in grid container is because I want to show these items as grid in desktop screens using grid and vertically in mobile screens using flexbox

Comment: Hope you understand my problem now

Comment: Why would you switch to flexbox for mobile? You can make the items 100% wide so they will be shown below each other.

Comment: Because in mobile version, item2 should come first then item1 and then item3. It can be achieved applying flexbox order property on each item. And in desktop layout should be like shown in image.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman You should be able to do the reordering in grid as well so you don't need to implement two solutions. Also please have a look at the new solution. Is this better?

Comment: Hey man, your solution should be fine if it possible to convert the same markup into mobile screens requirement. Can you tell me how to vertically place  items in the following order (item2 -> item1 -> item3) using your markup for mobile screens?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Use media queries for that, easily switch to flexbox for smaller screen, ordering is not a big deal in flexbox.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I've added the media query for smaller 600px (you can put in whatever you like of course). It will be 100% wide with your ordering now applied.

Comment: @SuryanshSingh I'd rather not switch the whole structure to flexbox. Slows down the website. If you already have grid you should stick to it unless you really are out of options.

Comment: @F.Müller thanks man, this is exactly what I want. I am new to css grid, I have learn the fundamentals of css grid but not yet fully understand the power of it. Today, I learn something from you, thanks again.

Comment: @F.Müller oh didn't knew about slowing down thing, OP was mentioning flexbox so it kind of stuck to mind, btw great answer.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Glad I could help. Tbh. I am also not really good at grid yet either. It is quite challenging to get used to it. It comes down to trial and error sometimes.

Comment: @SuryanshSingh Well if would hide it in the DOM then it should not really affect the performance of course. But if you had both solutions in place you would need to render both and let the DOM do its work (also additional media-query required). Well, it is a very small impact, but still. Why would you have both? I mean it's math behind it and events that will fire if the DOM or viewport changes so the less calculations you have to do the better.

Comment: @F.Müller I start learning grid a while ago but since I don't use grid in practice very much that's why its easy to forgot about it after a while but now I will definitely give time to grid as its a very powerful feature added to css.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I tend to use Grid mostly for the big wireframe structure. And flexbox for the smaller bits. Sometimes it makes more sense to use flexbox. Grid is more table-like. There are some limits e.g. masonry layout - you can read about that.

Comment: @F.Müller I will definitely take a look at it.